# How many non-negative integral solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ have?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many solutions does the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 10$ have,

> $1$) when $x_1 = 2$?

> $2$) when $x_1 \geq 2$?

> where $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ are nonnegative integers.

Am I doing this correctly? For ($1$) I have $\binom{2 + 8 -1}{8}$.

and for ($2$) I have $\binom{3 + 8 - 1}{8}$.

Thanks!

Comment: i guess positve integer solutions? may $x_1=x_2$ and so on ?

Comment: oh crap yeah, let me fix that

Comment: your answer is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of solutions is how many ways you can split ten 1's with 2 zeros. For the first one a 0 and two 1's are fixed already so we have to choose where to put a zero in  eight 1's. So it should be ${9} \choose {1} $ so the first is correct.

For the second you can consider it as asking how many sokutions does $ 2 +y + z=10 $ have without restriction. This is ${10} \choose {2} $. So your answer is correct again!

Answer (score 3):

Using the language of stars and bars,

$1)$ This represents having $1$ bar between $8$ stars:

$$ 8+1 \choose 1 $$

$2)$  This represents placing $2$ bars between $8$ stars:

$$ 8+2 \choose 2 $$

So yes, your answers both seem fine although you might like this dual way of thinking about it (finding where we put the '+' rather than where we put the numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Mh I don't know exactly how you came to those formulas, my idea is the following:

For $x_1=2$, We have $x_2+x_3=8$ so there are 9 solutions

For $x_1=3$ ,we have $x_2+x_3=7$ and so there 8 solutions, and so on till $x_1=10$

So we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^9 i =\frac{9 \cdot 10}{2} = \binom{10}{2}=\binom{10}{8}$$
which is the same as your solutions.

Neverthe less you should mention how you came to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your answer: You are doing this correctly. But maybe you should evalute the expressions.

Comment: i guess, if you have nothing more to add, this suits best as a comment

Comment: Avatar: Why? I think this is a full answer to the question. What is missing in your opinion?

Comment: When you answer here, you answer not only the person who asked the problem but for the future browsers too. So, OP might know how he got that answer, and you are verifying it(no problem with that), but you could explain a little more how one reaches that answer.

Comment: Avatar: I don't agree. The question was "Was I doing this correctly" and not "Please make my answer more elaborate". If a future reader has a related question, he can just ask and reference to this one.

Comment: wouldn't it be great if he could just visit this question and save his time by not typing another question which is same as this.That's my point. If you don't agree with that then no point of stretching this conversation. Let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @Avatar: If, in your opinion, this answer is not the best, just don't upvote. However, it does seem to be an answer; even though it would be a fine comment.