# How many solutions does the equation $x+y+z=11$ have?

Tags: combinatorics

How many solution does $x+y+z=11$ have **where $x, y, z$ are non-negative integers**. In light of the restrictions, its clear that $x,y,z \in \{0,1,2,..11\}$. So, at face value I would assign a value for $x$ and determine the different combinations that $y$ and $z$ can hold. For example,

For $x=0$, we have $y+z=11$. With writing them out I found that there are $12$ different assigned combinations for $y$ and $z$ that satisfy the equation. For $x=1$, I got $11$. Consequently, the pattern becomes clear whereby each one takes a value less by one. Hence, the number of solutions is $1+2+3+4+5+6+7..+12=78$. I was wondering if there is an easier method perhaps with combinations equation $C(a,b)$..?

Comment: We have had too many questions of this type.

Comment: See my answer here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689975/distributing-n-different-things-among-r-persons/690036#690036

Comment: Guys, stop upvoting duplicate homework questions, seriously!

Comment: @Alec Lighten up. The OP shows plenty of effort, and arrives at the correct answer in doing so. It deserves an upvote. John likely didn't know that this is a classic sort of problem, and probably hasn't encountered it before. Nor that many *similar* questions can be answered by the same method. And if you believe it is a duplicate and should be slammed shut because of it, then why'd you answer it? Besides, stop playing the homework police on questions showing commendable levels of effort!

Comment: @amWhy Not thinking something deserves an upvote isn't the same as saying it deserves to be closed. When I upvote something, what I personally mean is "this is the kind of content I come to the site for". My preferred policy would for routine problems to be dealt with quickly and without fanfare (positive or negative), and to save upvotes (and therefore time on the front page) for the more original, thought-provoking questions.

Comment: @JackM You are fully entitled to vote as you described. But that shouldn't be taken to say that "all folks should vote like this" or that "my policy should be everyone's policy."

Comment: @AlecTeal I have to ask you a question? Based on what premise, did you deduce that this is a homework question? Unfortunately, everyone(well let me say most of the people) on this website jumps to false conclusions and make hasty generalizations, and I wonder how do they get to it. Please enlighten me. If things aren't clear enough, I must say that this isn't a homework problem, but I doubt it could change your mind because clearly its made up.

Comment: @Awesome I just realized that there are many similar questions, although I made a previous search. In any case, though I have flagged my question as a duplicate.

Comment: @John because homework questions (or stuff from books) are on the same lines and it has been discussed to death. I remember my combinatorics assignments.....  :P

Comment: @AlecTeal Let me clarify that a question does not *necessarily* have to be a homework question. As such, I recommend not making any false assumptions and inductive fallacies; it doesn't hurt to ask the OP. Furthermore, if it was a homework question, now would I be here if I had the answer. Ultimately, my goal in asking the question is to understand and I have done so. It would be most unproductive to label future questions "homework" especially here where it unfortunately takes a pejorative tone.

Comment: @AlecTeal Homework or not, a question is a question. The final goal is to understand and you or anyone for that matter shouldn't stop the OP from learning.

Comment: @AlecTeal On that note, I appreciate the answer you gave below, it says that you want to help, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a version of the classic [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem in combinatorics.

For any pair of natural numbers $n$ and $k$, the number of distinct $n$-tuples of **non-negative** integers whose sum is $k$ is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n + k - 1}{k}$$

Here, $n = 3$, and $k = 11$, giving you $$\binom{3 + 11 - 1}{11} = \binom{13}{11} = \dfrac{13\cdot 12}{2} = 6\cdot 13 = 78$$

Comment: The link takes you to Wikipedia's Stars and Bars entry, where you'll find a nice explanation of why this works, using an example that's fleshed out nicely.

Comment: Using the formula makes things easy, but I don't see what the connection is. Even with using the stars and bars method, it seems rather inappropriate, due to the dependency of the variables. In other terms, if x takes a value it creates a dependency on the other variables. I would appreciate it if you could make the connection clearer.

Comment: Did you read the Wikipedia entry? It elaborates on the "why's" of this formula.

Comment: I read it and I understood everything but when I went to this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322369/how-many-non-negative-integral-solutions-does-the-equation-x-1-x-2-x-3-10, with the additional restrictions I started to doubt everything. None of the answers that used combinations were clear.

Comment: First get comfortable without the restrictions, getting a firm grasp on the *non-negative* integers, and the number of positive integers. *Then* we can begin adding restrictions.

Comment: Another confusing thing for me was the zero. I was considering it to be an element, i.e. to be represented by a star. But, after thinking about it I figured it out. I still have to figure out a greater than restriction like $x>2$

Comment: Well, taking a simple example: $x_1 + x_2 = 11$, where the $x\gt 2$, we can simply replace each $x_i$ with $x_i = y_i +  2$ and solve $y_1 + 2 + y_2+ 2 = 11 \iff y_1+y_2 = 7$. Then we have the case in which we are seeking the number of positive integer solutions to  $y_1 + y_2 = 7$.

Comment: I deleted my comment, but let me re-add as I think its correct. I said we first initialize everything so if we have $x>=2$. We have to put two stars for x as such: **|-|- . Now the remaining stars are $11-2= 9$. And to put 9 indistinguishable objects in 3 distinct boxes we need $C(3+9-1,9)$

Comment: Its correct, right?

Comment: You'd need to subtract from you total $11$, *two* stars for each $x_i$, giving you $5$ stars to work with. For example, for $x_1 + x_2+x_3 = 11$, putting $x_i = y_i + 2$ gives us $y_1 + 2 + y_2 + 2 + y_3 + 2 = 11 \iff y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 5$. Then the number of integer solutions greater than or equal to $0 = \binom{5+3 - 1}{5}$

Comment: Are you sure because  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322369/how-many-non-negative-integral-solutions-does-the-equation-x-1-x-2-x-3-10 here the suggested and thereafter confirmed answer is $C(3+8-1,8)$. Its 8 because instead of 11, its 10. So, $10-2=8$

Comment: Are you still there? Is the solution to that problem wrong?

Comment: In that problem, it  specifies only *one* variable $x$ being greater than or equal to two.  My work shows what you get when the restriction is that all the variables must be integers greater than or equal to 2. So the principal is the same. For each variable needing to be $\geq 2$, we subtract 2 for each such variable.

Comment: So, what I wrote is correct since I specified $x\ge 2$ and not $y$ or $z$

Comment: Yes. I see you used $x, y, z$, so if only $x$ needs to be greater than or equal to 2, then the solution (with k=11 - 2 = 9) is $\binom{3 + 9 - 1}{9}$.

Comment: You're welcome, John!

Answer (score 0):

imagine 11 balls in a row and two blocks which you will place somewhere. you insert the blocks before, after or between the balls and then you assign values to $x,y,z$ in the following way: $x$ is the number of balls from the beginning of the row up to the first block, $y$ the number of balls between the two blocks and $z$ number of balls from the second block up until the end of the row. you will easily see that the number of ways in which you can place the blocks is equal to the number of different triplets $x,y,z$. Do you know how to compute the number of possible distributions of blocks?

Comment: call it stars and bars if you don't like blocks and balls, but this is the usual way to approach such problems

Comment: it's an answer explained in a tangible way. actually it's pretty much the same thing you gave as an answer although it's explained with words rather than a picture.

Comment: Oh right! You could have laid it out nicer, I thought you did some weird thing that'd result in a 3! somewhere

Comment: Could you edit the answer so I may at least remove my DV?

Answer (score 0):

Okay let us write a solution to $a+b+c+d+e=10$ a different question, just incase it is homework.

Each solution will have the form:

```
||||-|---||||| <-> 4As 1B 0Cs, 0Ds, 5Es
```

How many different ways can we arrange 10 |s and 4 (4=5-1) -s?
Each arrangement of these |s and -s is a valid solution.

$$\frac{(10+4)!}{4!10!}=\frac{14!}{10!4!}$$